# Why is щ transliterated as "shch"?

Tags: произношение, транслитерация

It doesn't match with the pronunciation of the letter in Russian at all. A transliteration closer to the spelling would be rather "shj", "sh' " or something similar.

Besides, I've seen it transliterated like this in French ("chtch") and German ("schtsch") as well.

Why is that so? Is it etymological?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me quote my own [answer](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/difference-in-pronunciation-between-%D1%89-and-%D1%88%D1%8C/1722#1722) to a related question, [Difference in pronunciation between “щ” and “шь”?](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/):

> As for `щ`, it is a **long** alveopalatal consonant, IPA symbol for it is [/ɕː/](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_alveolo-palatal_sibilant) (you can listen to the sound there, and there is also the [sound for the Russian word 'счастье'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Ru-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5.ogg) [ˈɕːæsʲtʲjə] in which 'сч' is pronounced as 'щ'). Roughly speaking, in Standard Russian it is pronounced like the English 'shsh' in the phrase 'the dish she likes'. Some people pronounce `щ` as 'шч', but this pronunciation is considered obsolete.

The fact is, that although now the standard pronunciation of `щ` is /ɕː/, it used to be pronounced as /ɕtɕ/ and is still pronounced so by many people, that is why it is *traditionally* transliterated as `shch` in English. Note, that when the Cyrillic script emerged in the 9th century, `щ` stood for the consonantal cluster [ɕtʲ], and later in Russian [ɕtʲ] > [ɕtɕ] > [ɕː]. Thus, the tranliteration of this letter as `shch` reflects the previous stage of its pronunciation which is dying out now.

Comment: Спасибо. Значит, транслитерация базируется на традиционном произношение. А в каких местах произносится традиционным образом ? Спрашиваю, потому за год жизни в Сибири ни разу не слышал этого произношения. Причем в других местах СНГ, где был, тоже не слышал...

Comment: @almerillat - Я про Россию точно не знаю, возможно в Питере. И скорее всего в Одессе и вообще по Украине, под влиянием украинского языка, в котором `щ` произносится как [ʂtʂ].

Comment: @almerillat В Ульяновской области "щи" произносят как "счи"
А между гласными "щ" произносят как "шш" с отвердением последующей и до ы. Блестяшшый.

В Питере щ произносят как щ.