# Сколькими способами в русской орфографии может быть обозначена фонема [щ'] /ɕː/?

Tags: орфография, буква, звук

Есть авторы учебников, которые везде оперируют понятием «звук». Например, [Литневская](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part1#4_1). Но, вероятно, правильнее говорить «фонема». Итак, сколькими различными способами, согласно русской орфографии, может обозначаться звук или фонема [щ'] (по МФА — /ɕː/), как в начале слова «щука»?

Пишут, что, к примеру, есть вариант передачи [щ'] буквосочетанием [ЗЩ](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/1719/difference-in-pronunciation-between-%D1%89-and-%D1%88%D1%8C). Но мне что-то не припоминается такого слова. Может, кто-нибудь подскажет? Буду благодарен.

Comment: Например, резщик (как часто ошибочно пишут) или поизщипать - как никто не пишет, потому что редкий глагол, но орфографически переданный корректно. Это не вопрос русской орфографии - это вопрос речевой нормы.  Нет ответа на такой вопрос хотя бы потому что одни произносят слово дождь так а некоторые эдак.

Comment: @shabunc - К сожалению, «поизщипать» орфографически передан _не_ корректно. В приставках, оканчивающихся на З и С, написание конечной согласной зависит от произношения: перед глухими согласными произносят [с] и пишут «с», а перед звонкими согласными и гласными произносят [з] и пишут «з»: http://gramota.ru/class/coach/tbgramota/45_60 Поэтому правильно писать «пои**с**щипать».

Comment: @YellowSky бью себя по лбу рукой от досады - вы конечно правы!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В пределах одного орфографического слова без дефиса /ɕː/ кроме буквы Щ может обозначаться сочетаниями букв:

ЖЧ: мужчина
ЗЧ: грузчик
СЧ: счёт
ССЧ: рассчитать
ЖЩ: межщёчный*
СЩ: расщепить
ЖДЬ: дождь /doɕː/, произносят также [doʂtʲ]

ЗЩ: гагаузщина, или даже Гагаузщина – употребления в русском гуглом не регистрируются, но это вполне адекватное слово, построенное по продуктивной словообразовательной модели. Просто о гагаузах на русском пишут крайне мало.
8 обнаружений в Гугле даёт слово [*сказщик*](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&hl=uk&sxsrf=ALeKk00D6zjS49sxncB-ImbhrwLISiqHLw:1614807856431&q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi3uaaFjJXvAhVp-ioKHVBGBkcQvgUoAXoECA4QNg&biw=1662&bih=806&dpr=1.13), но по правилам русского правописания [следовало бы](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/666-325_pravopisanie_suffiksov_imen_suschestvitelnyh.html) писать *сказчик*.

---

*межщёчный – у блох на голове имеется *межщёчный отросток*.